# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, foreign-keys, sql-insert

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "party_custom_fields" violates foreign key constraint "fk21oqkpi7046skme7jce06fxdu"
```

Below error could help, what need to be done on the code, I have tried few reference, but not helpful.

`Detail: Key (custom_field_value)=(11) is not present in table "custom_field_value"`

Above is my error while saving.

Party is the class which will have custom fields and it's data

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "party")
public class Party {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "party_custom_fields",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "custom_field")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "custom_field_value")})
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "custom_field_key")
    private Map<Long, CustomFieldValue> customField = new HashMap<>();
    public Party() {
    }
    public Party(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Custom fields value model

```
package org.aeq.multitenant.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_field_value")
public class CustomFieldValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String value;

}
```

Custom fields model which hold what are the custom fields for the tables

```
package org.aeq.multitenant.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.aeq.multitenant.enums.Tables;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_field")
public class CustomField {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean optional;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "table_name")
    private Tables tableName;
}
```

Controller function to save

```
 Map<Long, CustomFieldValue> cfMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (CustomField cf : customFields) {
            if (!partyData.containsKey(cf.getName())) {
                return new ApiResult<>(false, "Please provide " + cf.getName() + " custom field of party");
            } else {
                CustomFieldValue cfv = new CustomFieldValue();
                cfv.setValue(partyData.get(cf.getName()).trim());
                cfv = customFieldValueRepository.save(cfv);
                cfMap.put(cf.getId(), cfv);
            }
        }

        Party party = new Party();
        party.setName(partyData.get("name"));
        party.setEmail(partyData.get("email").trim());
        party.setGender(partyData.get("gender").trim());
        party.setLastName(partyData.get("last_name").trim());
        party.setCustomField(cfMap);

        party = partyRepository.save(party);
```

please review my code and let me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

If a column has a foreign key constraint, then any entry to that column should be present in the reference table given. If not, then this exception will be thrown.

Comment: Im not aware of spring-boot. But I think in table **party_custom_fields** you have a **foreign_key constraint** on a column. If you have a **foreign key constraint 
 on a sub_table_column** then all the **values which are to be inserted** into that column **should already be present in the parent_table_column**

Comment: any how I have solved the issue with sql, instead of JpaRepository, I have used the entity manager which does the same as jpa, it works fine